# Who were the attendees to the SGA3 seminar?

Tags: mathematicians, grothendieck

Here is a photograph of the audience of SGA3 (as noted by Mateo Carmona).

[image]

Other photographs may be viewed from the homepage: https://agrothendieck.github.io/

Grothendieck is facing the audience. I recognise Dieudonne at the left in the front row, Mandelbrot (?) in the second row, Chevalley to the right of Mandelbrot, but no one else. (Corrections after comments.)

Does anyone recognise the others?

Comment: I'd agree that Dieudonne is on the far left, but I don't see Serre there at all, neither Nash. I do not have a clear recollection of Mandelbroit...

Comment: Do you mean *Mandelbrot*?

Comment: The [conference lecture notes](https://wstein.org/sga/sga5/SGA5.pdf) include lectures by Pierre Deligne, Grothendieck, Michel Raynaud, Serre, and John Stallings.  The lecture notes also mention Christian Houzel, Luc Illusie, and Jean Pierre Jouanolou. See also the Springer edition of the [conference proceedings](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0096802),  edited by Illusie

Comment: The older person (white hair) with a tie on to the right of G’s elbow looks like Chevalley. He was in Paris starting in 1957.

Comment: @KCd Yes, you are correct.  That is Chevalley, not Nash.

Comment: @paulgarrett My mistake, that could not be Serre as he was much younger then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Only one left (of those visible) to be identified. The man in the middle of C. Chevalley and P. Samuel.

The seminar is not very likely to be SGA 5 but SGA 3 ("Schémas en groupes") by M. Demazure and A. Grothendieck (some day between 1962 and 1964).

Photo credits: René Bouillot - Archives IHES